# Paypal PHP API SDK - Set Email Address for person purchasing

Tags: php, api, paypal, sdk

I want to set the email address for the person buying the product.  This is what I've got so far (as per the documentation):

```
$payer = new \PayPal\Api\Payer();
$payer  ->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

$amount = new \PayPal\Api\Amount();
$amount->setTotal($order['totals']['grand']);
$amount->setCurrency('GBP');

$itemList = new \PayPal\Api\ItemList();

$shipping_address = new \PayPal\Api\ShippingAddress();
$shipping_address->setRecipientName($order['shipping']['name']);
$shipping_address->setLine1($order['billing']['add1']);
$shipping_address->setLine2($order['billing']['add2']);
$shipping_address->setCity($order['shipping']['add3']);
$shipping_address->setPostalCode($order['shipping']['postcode']);
$shipping_address->setCountryCode(countryData($order['shipping']['countryID'],"code"));
$shipping_address->setPhone($order['shipping']['telephone']);
$itemList->setShippingAddress($shipping_address);

$transaction = new \PayPal\Api\Transaction();
$transaction->setAmount($amount)->setItemList($itemList);

$redirectUrls = new \PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls   ->setReturnUrl("https://example.com/shop/thank-you/")
                ->setCancelUrl("https://example.com/shop/cancelled/");

$payment = new \PayPal\Api\Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale')
        ->setPayer($payer)
        ->setTransactions(array($transaction))
        ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);  

try {
    $payment->create($apiContext);
    predump(json_decode($payment));

    echo "\n\n<a href='".$payment->getApprovalLink()."'>Redirect user to approval_url</a>\n";
}
catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
    // This will print the detailed information on the exception.
    //REALLY HELPFUL FOR DEBUGGING
    echo $ex->getData();
}
```

As far as I can gather from the shitshow of documentation that Paypal put out, and from the many various pages from googling, I want to set the email address in the Payer() (`$payer`) class - how do I do that?

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [PayerInfo](https://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/docs/class-PayPal.Api.PayerInfo.html), this should work:

```
$payerInfo = new \PayPal\Api\PayerInfo();
$payerInfo ->setEmail('example@email.com');

$payer = new \PayPal\Api\Payer();
$payer  ->setPaymentMethod('paypal');
$payer ->setPayerInfo($payerInfo);
```

Comment: Thank you.  I couldnt find that anywhere, no matter what I searched for.  I knew it would be easy too!  I hate their documentation lol.

Comment: Yeah, I remember the pain when I had to implement this in C# !
You're welcome :)